# SSMS IntelliSense doesn't work on particular database

Tags: sql-server, ssms, intellisense

I have SSMS 2014 installed on my desktop, and many 2012 and 2014 databases running in our data center.

So far I found one database (database A) doesn't have IntelliSense working, for exampletyping:

```
SELECT [put cursor here] FROM sys.objects
```

and moving cursor between select and from, pressing <kbd>CTRL + J</kbd>, I can see popup options for other databases, just not for database A. I have checked all options and refresh local cache, all don't work,  and I am using an account which has *sysadmin* permission.

- The compatibility level is 11.0
- Version is

  > Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5556.0 (X64) Oct 31 2014 16:50:24 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: )

I can log on to the db server which is in US and see IntelliSense working there, it just doesn't on my desktop (in Australia). Is it most likely a latency issue? is there a timeout limit or setting for this feature?

Comment: See the [bit here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2591/troubleshooting-intellisense-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012/) that starts with, "And finally, you may just need to be patient." I suspect this particular database is a lot more objects, a lot of schemas, or has a very complex set of dependency chains. Once it finally all loads, you should be fine, as long as your network connectivity is somewhat reliable and there aren't a lot of schema changes happening. Leaving Management Studio open instead of opening/closing it a lot should relieve some of this too.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, it makes sense, but I still cannot make it working, it is very likely the poor network connectivity between US datacenter and AU Datacenter.

Comment: You could also try [mssql-cli](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2017/12/12/try-mssql-cli-a-new-interactive-command-line-tool-for-sql-server/) to see if it performs any better being a bit more lightweight. [ApexSQL Complete](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_complete.aspx) is also free and may be worth a try as well. I recall it *working* on larger databases but still being somewhat laggy when it listed items.

Answer (score 6):

It might be latency, or it might be something else. Run a SQL Server Profiler trace on the remote DB, starting the trace just prior to connecting via SSMS remotely. IntelliSense works by running queries to get the meta-data, so you will be able to see if it is even attempting to work or not, and if so, potentially if it is running into any problems.

You should filter the `ApplicationName` column on `LIKE %IntelliSense%`, though the full name of the program is `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Transact-SQL IntelliSense`. Events to select: `SQL:BatchStarting`, `SQL:BatchCompleted`, `SQL:StmtStarting`, `SQL:StmtCompleted`, `SP:Starting`, `SP:Completed`, `SP:StmtStarting`, `SP:StmtCompleted`, `RPC:Starting`, and `RPC:Completed`.

Try it first on a DB that works so you know what the normal / expected behavior should look like. Hitting <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to force a reload of the local cache should produce a decent amount of activity captured by your trace.